# Anylogic: Measuring time spent in service

Tags: time, anylogic, utilization

In the following model [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHhc9.png) the graph visualizes the service block's utilization. However, this utilization represents the average number of agents being processed.

I would like to find out the amount of time the service block is delaying agents during the model's total run time. This would provide me with a more accurate representation of the capacity utilization. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a dataset or a statistics element (found in the analysis palette) or even a collection and add values like this:
[image: Service delayed time]

On enter delay:

```
agent.enterTime=time();
```

On exit (or on at exit)

```
data.add(time()-agent.enterTime);
```

Of course this requires you to add a variable called enterTime in your agent.

Comment: This would not work with an assembler since it creates a new agent correct?

Comment: you are correct, with the assembler it would be different